# How to render graphics on Linux server

Tags: linux, graphics, glfw, reinforcement-learning

This will probably be a dumb question to many. I rented a Linux (CentOS) server to run some simulation experiments using [MuJoCo](http://www.mujoco.org/index.html). I have got most of the things installed, and I am running the python script to spin up an environment to collect data. [Here](https://github.com/berkeleydeeprlcourse/homework/blob/master/hw1/run_expert.py) is the python script. It gives me this error:

```
Exception: glfw failed to initialize
Fatal Python error: Couldn't create autoTLSkey mapping
Aborted
```

I guess I was expecting this because there is no way that a pure shell environment will start rendering colourful graphics. As far as I understood from reading online, `glfw` is an OpenGL framework to render graphics. My pure shell environment is incapable of such tasks.

Is there a way that I can get the graphics to work? Can I tunnel the graphics layer to my laptop?

Note: I have no idea how graphics work so this question might annoy some experts, so getting some online pointers or a succinct description will be extremely helpful.

Comment: I guess, if you have no graphics output at all and no window system, you are stuck. See [glfw documentation](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context.html#context_offscreen). Under certain circumstances, you may get it working (see [this](https://github.com/IntelVCL/Open3D/issues/17) and [this](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/648) issue).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not supported.

From the [`glfw` docs](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context.html#context_offscreen):

> GLFW doesn't support creating contexts without an associated window.

You can see from GitHub issues such as [this one](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/issues/482) that it has been a requested feature.